# How to sum values of array based on Key using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, yii, array-merge

```
for ($row = 0; $row < 25; $row++) {
    $bQuery = 'Select date, billed from {$tableArray[$row][1]}';
    $bProvider = new CSqlDataProvider($bQuery, array('pagination'=>false));
    $Arr2 = $bProvider->getData();
    // merging array to get all loop records in single array
    $array_2 = array_merge($array_2, $Arr2);
}
```

Then print_r `$array_2` output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2016-11-00
            [billed] => 100
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2016-12-00
            [billed] => 400
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2016-11-00
            [billed] => 200
        )
     // so on
)
```

I want to sum `billed` where `date is same`. So here is my code which works for it.

```
$result = array();
foreach ($array_2 as $data) {
    @$result[$data['date']] += $data['billed'];
}

print_r($result);

$newresultGraph = array();
foreach ($result as $date => $billed) {
    $newresultGraph[] = array('date' => $date, 'billed' => $billed);
}

print_r($newresultGraph);
```

The `print_r($result)`  in above codes returns me data like this below, It has already summed the values for the same date.

```
Array
(
    [2016-11-00] => 300
    [2016-12-00] => 400
)
```

Then in my above code after another foreach loop, Im making my data like before in array. when i `print_r($newresultGraph)`, My data is like this.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2016-11-00
            [billed] => 300
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2016-12-00
            [billed] => 400
        )

)
```

This is working perfectly for me.. because my query was this.

`Select date, billed from table'`

I was getting only `date`, `billed` from table but now i have another field so my query is like this..

```
Select 
date, 
billed, 
((billed * rate) * (myValue) / 100) as my_rev,
((billed * rate) * (opValue) / 100) as op_rev,
From table
```

So i have two new values which are `my_rev` and `op_rev`

Then print_r `$array_2` output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2016-11-00
            [billed] => 100
            [my_rev] => 30
            [op_rev] => 70
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2016-12-00
            [billed] => 400
            [my_rev] => 150
            [op_rev] => 250
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2016-11-00
            [billed] => 200
            [my_rev] => 50
            [op_rev] => 150
        )
     // so on
)
```

which is correct,

I want to sum the values of all billed, my_rev, op_rev for a date.. I don't want to sum billed+my_rev+op_rev..

I want my array to be like this below: It should sum all the values of billed into billed, similarly for my_rev and op_rev.

Just like below example.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2016-11-00
            [billed] => 300
            [my_rev] => 80
            [op_rev] => 220
        )
[1] => Array
    (
        [date] => 2016-12-00
        [billed] => 400
        [my_rev] => 150
        [op_rev] => 250
    )

)
```

My above code is turning my `print_r($result)` into like this:

```
Array
(
    [2016-11-00] => 600
    [2016-12-00] => 800
)
```

What should i do? any other suggestion?

Comment: So if your solution works for `billed`, what's preventing you from doing the same for `my_rev` and `op_rev`?

Comment: My `print_r($result)` is summing all values into one.. like this `Array
(
    [2016-11-00] => 600
    [2016-12-00] => 800
)`

Comment: You didn't provide any example of how my_rev and op_rev is summed up. You should. There's plenty of unrelated code in there also like the SQL statements. On that note though, you could probably fetch the desired values for all three straight from the database using aggregates.

Comment: They should sum up same like billed

Comment: What is the purpose of the first `for` loop where you assign `$row` values, but never use `$row` in the body of the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your 2nd last foreach like this and then print the result array and see it will sum values with their keys.

```
$result = array();
foreach ($array_2 as $data) {
    @$result[$data['date']]['billed'] += $data['billed'];
    @$result[$data['date']]['my_rev'] += $data['my_rev'];
    @$result[$data['date']]['op_rev'] += $data['op_rev'];
}
```

You can change your last foreach accordingly if you need it.

Result with your values:

Input:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [date] => 2016-11-00
        [billed] => 100
        [my_rev] => 30
        [op_rev] => 70
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [date] => 2016-12-00
        [billed] => 400
        [my_rev] => 150
        [op_rev] => 250
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [date] => 2016-11-00
        [billed] => 200
        [my_rev] => 50
        [op_rev] => 150
    )

)
```

Result:

```
Array
(
[2016-11-00] => Array
    (
        [billed] => 300
        [my_rev] => 80
        [op_rev] => 220
    )

[2016-12-00] => Array
    (
        [billed] => 400
        [my_rev] => 150
        [op_rev] => 250
    )
)
```

Comment: Do not use http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php.

Comment: This also doesn't take into account sorting.

Answer (score 1):

This code does it :

```
$tmp_array = array();
foreach ($array as $val) {
    if (array_key_exists($val['date'], $tmp_array)) {
        $tmp_array[$val['date']]['billed'] += $val['billed'];
        $tmp_array[$val['date']]['my_rev'] += $val['my_rev'];
        $tmp_array[$val['date']]['op_rev'] += $val['op_rev'];
    } else {
        $tmp_array[$val['date']]['date'] = $val['date'];
        $tmp_array[$val['date']]['billed'] = $val['billed'];
        $tmp_array[$val['date']]['my_rev'] = $val['my_rev'];
        $tmp_array[$val['date']]['op_rev'] = $val['op_rev'];
    }
}

$result = array_values($tmp_array);
```

OUTPUT :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2016-11-00
            [billed] => 300
            [my_rev] => 80
            [op_rev] => 220
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2016-12-00
            [billed] => 400
            [my_rev] => 150
            [op_rev] => 250
        )
    )
)
```

`$tmp_array` as the dates as keys in order to group the data, the last replaces these keys with succesive indexes. If you prefer to keep dates as keys - it's more optimized - or doesn't care, just call `$tmp_array` `$result` and delete the last line.

Comment: Instead of repeating `$val['date']`, you could extract a temporary variable, and also, in the `else` part, you could just assign an entire array in one go, instead of assigning values four times.

Comment: You are right, except that it's quite unsignificant optimization regarding what I assume to be the remaining code, so I went for easier to understand in case the OP whants to adjust it to needs he hasn't mentioned yet. But I would have written the same as you if it was my own code, I agree.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

- calculate sums in PHP
- calculate sums in SQL

### Calculate sums in PHP

```
$sql = <<<SQL
SELECT
    date, 
    billed, 
    billed * rate * myValue / 100 AS my_rev,
    billed * rate * opValue / 100 AS op_rev
FROM
    table
SQL;

$provider = new CSqlDataProvider($sql, array(
    'pagination' => false,
));

$rows = $provider->getData();

$data = array();

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $date = $row['date'];

    // initialize
    if (!array_key_exists($date, $data)) {
        $data[$date] = array(
            'date' => $date,
            'billed' => $row['billed',
            'my_rev' => $row['my_rev'],
            'op_rev' => $row['op_rev',
        );

        continue;
    }

    $data[$date]['billed'] += $row['billed'];
    $data[$date]['my_rev'] += $row['my_rev'];
    $data[$date]['op_rev'] += $row['op_rev'];
}

// sort by key, that is, sort by date
ksort($data);

// remove keys
$data = array_values($data);

var_dump($data);
```

### Calculate sums in SQL

```
$sql = <<<SQL
SELECT
    date, 
    SUM(billed), 
    SUM(billed * rate * myValue / 100) AS my_rev,
    SUM(billed * rate * opValue / 100) AS op_rev
FROM
    table
GROUP BY
    date
ORDER BY
    date ASC
SQL;

$provider = new CSqlDataProvider($sql, array(
    'pagination' => false,
));

$rows = $provider->getData();

var_dump($rows);
```

You decide for yourself which of these solutions you prefer. However, the latter requires less PHP code and after all, the database server can do some work, too, right?

Comment: I haven't tried your PHP yet, But i don't think the SQL one will work, Because I have an loop which runs on sql query for almost 25 times, After that I need to sum those values.

Comment: The loop doesn't make any sense with the code you posted. Update the example so we can tell what the purpose of the loop is, please.

Comment: Oops yeah i have updated the query, It was i have like 26 tables, I have put the names of table in `$tableArray then i  have used for loop to run it for 26 times to get records from each table.